# Stability region for two step Nyström method

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-theory

I have the following two step Nyström method: $u_{k+1}=u_{k-1}+2h\cdot f(u_k)$. **I want to know the stability region**, so I wrote this as $w_{k+1} = A\cdot w_k$ with $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 2h\lambda & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $w_k = (u_{k},u_{k-1})^t$. I use the sample/test equation $u'=\lambda\cdot u = f(u)$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. To find the stability region I must set some limitations on the matrix A.

Do I want the whole vector $w_{k+1}$ to go to the zero vector as $k$ goes to infinity, or just the first component that contains $u_{k+1}$? I don't think I can let the second component go to zero, since the matrix just has a $1$ in the bottomleft corner. **So I think I want $2h\lambda$ to be negative in the reals** (like Forward Euler) **, or at least less than 1?** I'm unfortunately just guessing at this point.

For (Forward) Euler we have $u_{k+1}=u_k + h\cdot f(u_k) = (1 + h\lambda)u_k$ and so we require that $h\lambda$ does not have a positive real part.

So I guess I also want some anologue for matrices being less than 1? I do not know how to deal with the matrices since the left hand vector not only contains $u_{k+1}$ but also the old $u_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $hλ\pm\sqrt{1+(hλ)^2}\approx \pm\exp(\pm hλ)$. The method is stable if for $Re(λ)<0$ the iteration converges to zero. As the product of the eigenvalues is always $-1$, you will always have one eigenvalue greater than $1$ in absolute value, and thus the component of the solution corresponding to it growing, not falling to $0$.

In conclusion, the method is nowhere stable.

Following Hairer/Wanner: *"Solving ODE II"*, ch. V.1 "Stability of multi-step methods", the characteristic polynomials here are $\rho(\zeta)=\zeta^2-1$ and $\sigma(\zeta)=2\zeta$ with characteristic equation $\rho(\zeta)-\mu\sigma(\zeta)=0$, where $\mu=hλ$, and $\zeta=e^{hλ}$ is the step factor of the exact solution.

Then the stability domain is defined as the set of all $\mu$ where the characteristic equation only has solutions in the closed unit disk. But again, here the solutions have product $-1$, so they can not all be inside the unit disk, and both roots are on the boundary for $\mu$ on the segment between $-i$ and $i$. This is called "weak instability" and causes the oscillating behavior (slowly increasing from floating point noise) shown in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067889/115115) resp. vol. I, chapter III.9 of the cited book.

Comment: Are you assuming $\lambda$ has to be a real number? It can be complex, I will update my question.

Comment: If I impose conditions on the real part of $λ$, it obviously can be complex.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying one component of the solution isn't falling to 0, but the second component can stay at 1, because that would just mean that the second component equals 1 times the same term because of the 1 in the bottom left?

Comment: No, it means that $u_k=aq^k+b(-q)^{-k}$ where $q=hλ+\sqrt{1+(hλ)^2}$ is the root closer to $1$. Assume $Re(λ)<0$ so that $|q|<1$, at least for small $h$. You can construct $u_1$ in such a way that $b=0$ initially. But during the computation floating point errors accumulate. Their contribution is distributed to both $a$ and $b$. With time, the first term will fall to zero, but in the second term $|q|^{-k}$ will be large enough that this term becomes noticeable, even if $b$ stays a small multiple of the machine number.

Comment: How do the eigenvalues of $A$ say anything about the stability? I know that if $\tau$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ we have that $A\cdot w_k=\tau\cdot w_k$. And where can I find more on how you get to the approximation $e^{h\lambda}$?

Comment: For $h$ small enough, $q=hλ+\sqrt{1+(hλ)^2}=hλ+(1+\frac12(hλ)^2-\frac18(hλ)^4+...)=e^{hλ}+O((hλ)^3)$. For stability you need $\|A^k\|\le 1$ for large $k$. The eigenvalues of $A$ tell you if that is the case.

Comment: How is that norm defined?

Comment: This is true for any operator norm, $\limsup \sqrt[n\,]{\|A^n\|}\le 1 $ if and only if all eigenvalues are $\le 1$ in abs. value and when $=1$ they have to be simple.

Comment: But if the product of the eigenvalues is -1, can't one eigenvalue be 1 and the other -1? So that neither of them grow? Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: Yes it can, for the differential equation $y'=0$, that is, for $λ=0$. Hopefully any implementation of a solver will return the constant solution in this case. Also for $y''=-y$ you get $λ=\pm i$ so that for $h<1$ the points $\pm ih\pm\sqrt{1-h^2}$ are on the unit circle. But that is the best you get.