# Solve initial value problem

Tags: numerical-methods, eulers-method

I have an exercise that I do not understand.
We have to solve an initial value problem:

> $$
> \begin{array}{ccl}
>  y'(t) &=& f(t,y(t)) \\
> y(a) &=& y_0
> \end{array}
> $$

We have to derive an effective method to calculate $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ with the highest possible accuracy. The method has the form below:
$$
y_{k+1} = \alpha y_k + \beta y_{k-1} + \gamma h f(t_k, y_k)
$$
We can even assume that $y_1 = y(a+h)$ and that the interval is equidistant.

I can guess that we have to derive a Euler forward, but I cannot solve it?
Besides, they ask the order of accuracy of the found method. Shall I write all the $y(a+h)$ as a Taylor polynomial? 
I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Writint out a Taylor polynomial would ideed be a good idea, I think.

Comment: No, it will not be Euler forward, the resulting method is a second order two-step midpoint or Nyström method, like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067795/115115), further explored [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3074952/115115).

Comment: I don't think it's a Nyström or modified Euler, it's a beginner course and we did not do those methods. I tried to make a Taylor polynomial but nothing disappears.

Comment: Simple order 2 methods are absolutely suited for a beginner course. Besides, this is more an exercise in Taylor polynomials than in numerical integration.

Comment: I still don't understand, can you please show what you mean and which parts I am supposed to develop with Taylor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the test problem $f(t,y)=y$ you get the exact solution $y=Ce^x$ and with the constant chosen so that $y_k=1$ the equation reduces to
$$
e^h=α+βe^{-h}+γh
$$
which has to be correct up to some power of $h$.

Inserting the power series of the exponential and comparing coefficients of equal degree gives
\begin{align}
γh&=(1+h+\tfrac12h^2+\tfrac16h^3+...)-α-β(1-h+\tfrac12h^2-\tfrac16h^3\pm...)
\\[1em]\hline
0&=1-α-β\\
γ&=1+β\\
0&=\tfrac12(1-β)\\
0&=\tfrac16(1+β)
\end{align}
which have to be satisfied from top down as far as possible. Obviously, the last equation contradicts the next-to-last one. Thus $β=1$, $γ=2$ and $α=0$.

You will need to confirm that this holds true for any differential equation, not just this (quite standard) test case.