# Find the stability function of $y_{n+1}-y_{n-1} = 2h\lambda y_n$

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm asked to find the stability function $R(z)$ in the expression $y_{n+1} = R(z)y_n$ given the method 
$$y_{n+1}-y_{n-1} = 2h\lambda y_n.$$ How do I do this? I can't do it when three stages is present in the equation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a stability function is? And what are $y_n, h, \lambda$?

Comment: The function $R(z)$ is in the recursion equation $y_{n+1}=R(z)y_n$. $y_n$ is the value at stage $n$, $h$ is the stepsize, $\lambda$ is a arbitrary real constant. I thought this was standard in a numerical methods context.

Comment: Thank you. It's probably standard, but I never had a numerical methods course, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Here you need two time steps in the state vector of the method, so that
$$
\pmatrix{y_{n+1}\\y_n}=R(z{=}λh)\pmatrix{y_n\\y_{n-1}}
=\pmatrix{2λh&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{y_n\\y_{n-1}}.
$$
For the stability you need to explore the eigenvalues of the matrix $R(z)$.

The two-step Nyström or central Euler method is only weakly stable, in that the stability region (where $R(z)$ is non-expanding) is the segment $[-i,i]$ on the imaginary axis.

- [Stability region for two step Nyström method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3074952/115115)
- [Deriving the central Euler method and intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067795/115115)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a general answer that you can specialize.

The region of absolute stability is found by applying a linear multi-step method to the problem $u'=\lambda u.$ Since the general form of such a method is $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^r\alpha_jU^{n+j}=k\sum\limits_{j=0}^r\beta_j f(U^{n+j},t_{n+j}),$$ applying it to the ODE gives
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^r\alpha_jU^{n+j}=k\sum\limits_{j=0}^r\beta_j \lambda U^{n+j}.$$ If we take $z=k\lambda,$ then we can re-write this as $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^r(\alpha_j-z\beta_j)U^{n+j}=0.$$ This is a linear difference equation with a solution of the form $$U^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^r c_j\zeta^n_j,$$ where $\zeta_j$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial $$\pi(\zeta;z)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^r(\alpha_j-z\beta_j)\zeta^j.$$ If you're familiar with the characteristic polynomials $$p(\zeta)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^r \alpha_j\zeta^j\ \ \ \  \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \sigma(\zeta)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^r \beta_j\zeta^j,$$ then we can write $$\pi(\zeta;z)=p(\zeta)-z\sigma(\zeta).$$
The region of absolute stability will be the $z$ for which the absolute polynomial satisfies the root condition.

Answer (score 0):

The difference equation

$$
y_{n+1}-2h\lambda y_n-y_{n-1} = 0
$$

has as solution

$$
y_n = C_1 \left(h\lambda-\sqrt{1+h^2\lambda^2}\right)^n+C_2\left(h\lambda+\sqrt{1+h^2\lambda^2}\right)^n
$$

and is is stable as long as

$$
\left\{\left|h\lambda-\sqrt{1+h^2\lambda^2}\right| < 1\right\}\cap \left\{\left|h\lambda+\sqrt{1+h^2\lambda^2}\right| < 1\right\}
$$

hence it is unstable.