# Stability region of explicit midpoint method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the explicit midpoint method, i.e
$$y_{n+1}-y_{n-1} = 2hf(y_n).$$

I'm asked to apply this method to the linear test equation, $f(y_n) = \lambda y_n,$ in order to find the method's stability region.

So I have 
$$y_{n+1}-y_{n-1} = 2h\lambda y_n.$$

In the problems I've done before I wouldn't have the $y_{n-1}$ term so I could just easily write $y_{n+1} = R(z)y_n.$ How would I solve this?

Comment: Since only $h \lambda$ appears here, clearly that's your $z$. Now if you had a one term recursion such as $y_{n+1} = R(z)y_n$, how would you determine the stability region? What is the next step?

Comment: @HansEngler Just simple algebra? I would write it in that form, and the stability region is where $R(z) \leq 1$. What confuses me is the $y_{n-1}$ term. I want to expess the $y_n$ term in terms of $y_{n-1}$ but I just end up in a endless loop of expressions.

Comment: Note that the explicit midpoint method is a two-stage Runge-Kutta method $k_1=hf(x_n,y_n)$, $k_2=hf(x_n+h/2,y_n+k_1/2)$, $y_{n+1}=y_n+k_2$.

Comment: See also [Deriving the central Euler method and intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067795/115115) on the same method and its implementation.